# Django tutorial: runserver error

Tags: python, django, macos

I'm following the django tutorial and i immediately ran into a problem on part 1.  After running python manage.py runserver i enter the URL into my browser and get an error:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class"
```

Below i included the error along with the version of python and django i'm running.  Any help would be much appreciated

```
^C172-29-17-104:mysite [redacted]$ python -V
Python 2.7.5

172-29-17-104:mysite [redacted]$ python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.6.4

172-29-17-104:mysite [redacted]$ python manage.py runserver

Validating models...

0 errors found
October 01, 2014 - 20:12:56
Django version 1.6.4, using settings 'mysite.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 31, in import_by_path
    error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
[01/Oct/2014 20:13:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__
    self.load_middleware()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 47, in load_middleware
    mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 31, in import_by_path
    error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a "SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/classpython manage.py runserver
```

Comment: `The Django tutorial` - provide a link, please!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using a version of django prior to version 1.7 (1.6.4 to be specific), and `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware` was not introduced until django 1.7. Hence the error

[Documentation can be found here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware)

On the bottom right, you can choose the version of django. Select the appropriate version, and follow the tutorial specific to the version of django you are using.

Comment: Hmmm so why would it be there if i'm not using version 1.7?

Comment: You probably copied the code from tutorial related to django 1.7, which is the cause of the issue.

Comment: i've been following these directions https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/  when i get to the runserver part is where i experience the error.  As the original post shows, i'm running python 2.7.5 and django 1.6.4    Any ideas why SessionAuthenticationMiddleware would be included?

Comment: in your settings.py, you most likely have an entry for the middleware causing the issue. Remove that line, or comment it out for now.

Comment: YES that worked!  Any idea why that was there if i'm using an older version of django?

Comment: I think it has to do with copying over some lines of code in settings, and this accidentally crept in ?

Answer (score 1):

just delete the following session authentication middleware  from your project settings.py

```
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
```