# A server error occurred. Django Application

Tags: python, django, server

All of my applications are having this problem, and yesterday all was ok!

```
mayke@mayke-notebook:~/$ python manage.py runserver 

Validating models...

0 errors found
January 05, 2015 - 17:41:52
Django version 1.6.1, using settings 'Teste.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Ok, is a new project, everything is ok, but when i try to access, I get the following error in browser:

```
A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.
```

And the following stacktrace at Terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__ return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__ self.load_middleware()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 31, in mport_by_path error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
[05/Jan/2015 17:45:19] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 59 Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 67, in __call__ return self.application(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__ self.load_middleware()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 45, in load_middleware mw_class = import_by_path(middleware_path)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 31, in import_by_path error_prefix, module_path, class_name))
ImproperlyConfigured: Module "django.contrib.auth.middleware" does not define a SessionAuthenticationMiddleware" attribute/class
```

Comment: Have you looked at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25879725/django-improperlyconfigured-module ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django tutorial: runserver error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26149876/django-tutorial-runserver-error)

Comment: 1.6.1 does not have `SessionAuthenticationMiddleware`, it wasn't introduced until 1.7